# Powershell Get-ChildItem extract username from profile folder

Tags: powershell, glob

I have drive where roaming user profiles are stored:

```
U:\Users\john.doe
U:\Users\john.wick
U:\Users\john.smith
```

I need to check if users have files with *.pdf extensions stored in their profiles

```
$a = Get-ChildItem "U:\users\" -Include *.pdf -Recurse | select FullName
foreach ($b in $a){

Write-Output $b



}
```

Output

```
U:\Users\john.wick\desktop\file.pdf
U:\Users\john.wick\documents\a.pdf
U:\Users\john.doe\desktop\1.pdf
..................................
```

I need to write column to extract username from path, and one  column with full file path.
How to do it ?

```
john.doe
john.wick
--------
```

Comment: Do you want the PDFs or just check IF the user has PDFs stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Get-ChildItem` *without* `-Recurse` to discover the profile folders, then use `Where-Object` + `Get-ChildItem` to find the ones containing pdfs:

```
$profilesWithPDFs = Get-ChildItem U:\Users\ -Directory |Where-Object { $_ |Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Filter *.pdf |Select -First 1 }
```

Once you've discovered the relevant folders, you can grab the name only:

```
$profilesWithPDFs |ForEach-Object -MemberName Name
```